# How to subclass django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields.PointField?

Tags: django, gis, geodjango

I have a [`django.contrib.gis.geos.point.Point`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.2/django/contrib/gis/geos/point.py#L6) subclass:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point

class Location(Point):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        lat = kwargs.get('latitude')
        lng = kwargs.get('longitude')

        if lat and lng:
            super(Location, self).__init__(lng, lat)
        elif lat or lng:
            raise TypeError(u'You must declare latitude and longitude, not '
                'just one of them.')
        else:
            super(Location, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.__class__ = Location

    def __unicode__(self):
        c = self.coordinates()
        return u'Location <Lat: %.5f, Lng: %.5f>' % (c['latitude'],
            c['longitude']) 

    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self).encode('utf-8')

    def coordinates(self):
        return {
            'latitude': self.coords[1], 
            'longitude': self.coords[0]
        }
```

Notice that this class has no extra information compared to super. It has only extra methods to facilitate its usage.

How can I create a [`django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields.PointField`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.2/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py#L268) subclass to use with `Location`? If I use `PointField` directly, it allows me to store a `Location` (because it is essentially a `Point`), But when I retrieve its content, it returns a `Point`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: When you say you receive its contents you mean that you fetch it from  a postgis db? If so it is logical. The database adapter of geodjango only knows Points, not your Location. And I wouldn't go down the road of trying to change that. Just create some helper functions for doing stuff on Points after you pulled them from the db.

Comment: Or you could override your models fetch method to return the Location instead of a point.